# Implement a delegate for two protocols

Tags: macos, lazarus, freepascal

I am lost on the syntax for creating a class that implements two protocols in FreePascal / Lazarus.

I do not want to define a new protocol (objcprotocol?) - I "simply" want a class that implement two protocols, here NSURLConnectionDelegate and NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, so I can use Mac API calls using delegates.

I have something along this

```
TmyDelegate = objcclass
public
  procedure connectionDidFinishLoading(UC: NSURLConnection); message 'connectionDidFinishLoading:';
  // + all other methods... And can I possibly inherit from a class that implements some of the routines, so I do not have to implement all?)
end;
```

However, I suspect I need to define/mark the class for which protocols are supported?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `'connectionDidFinishLoading:'`? i.e. the : at the end, not as a prefix?

Comment: Sorry - I typed in from Mac to Windows. You are correct. But the essence is that I am 100% far off in the correct declaration. I have no idea how to properly define it at present. The documentation about this online is not abundant :-/

Comment: Possibly I should have left out example code completely. I don't believe the objcclass is correct when defining a delegate.

Comment: Try http://wiki.freepascal.org/PasCocoa. It seems you need to register your classes and methods. Haven't tried this myself, sorry.